# Is it possible to have a specific app make noise and vibrate even when the phone is on silent?

Tags: notifications, 8.0-oreo, silent-mode

When I go to bed for the night I usually put my phone on silent without vibration, so that I don't get disturbed by constant notifications from meaningless things overnight.  However, I have an app that is used to alert me when I'm on-call at work, and I'd like that app to *always* have a notification sound and vibrate, *even when the phone is on silent*, so that it wakes me up if it goes off at night.

Is this possible with Android? I'm using a Galaxy S9 with Android 8.

Comment: How does that app alerts you? If it posts a notification than you can setup an automation app like MacroDroid to detect a notification from that app, remove DND or your silent preference, make a vibration along with a custom tone of yours and than restore your silent preference.

Comment: @Firelord it posts a notification. I'll look at MacroDroid. Is it like Trigger or IFTTT?

Comment: I am aware of neither. But it is powerful. Another and more powerful alternative is Tasker. Its trial version can be found on its website.

Comment: @Firelord Trigger is a lot like Tasker. Thanks. This might be the way to go.

Comment: Let us know if it works out for you. :)

Comment: I know this is late... but you could consider using "Do Not Disturb" (search in settings) instead of silencing your phone. Then you could go into the notification settings for the app and allow it as an exception to Do Not Disturb.